# markovifyをインストールしようとするとエラーが出る

Tags: python, windows, pip

`pip install markovify`
を実行すると次のようなエラーが出て次に進めません、どうすれば治りますか？

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\taiki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\taiki\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lep8bohx\\markovify\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\taiki\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lep8bohx\\markovify\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\taiki\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-p53sth73'
         cwd: C:\Users\taiki\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lep8bohx\markovify\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\taiki\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lep8bohx\markovify\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        long_description = f.read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 8016: illegal multibyte sequence
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: 手元の環境では再現できていないのですが、類似のエラーに対して様々な解決方法が提示されています。[Windows の環境変数で`PYTHONUTF8 を 1`と設定する](http://var.blog.jp/archives/78819289.html)、[`Lib/site-packages` に `sitecustomize.py` を作成して`sys.setdefaultencoding("cp932")`を記述する](https://qiita.com/Go-zen-chu/items/fdde8839935d2807b6cd)、[`chcp`でコマンドプロンプトの文字コードをUTL-8にする](https://qiita.com/akabei/items/da70ebf61cc413d5ff0d)。何らかの方法で解決しましたら自己回答またはコメントでお教えいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

pip コマンドを実行する前に `set PYTHONUTF8=1` というコマンドを実行してみてください。

Pythonがテキストファイルを開く時にデフォルトで使う文字コードが、Unix(macOSやLinuxなど)ならロケール、WindowsだとGetACP()が返すコードページ（日本語ならcp932、いわゆるShift-JIS）を使います。

ですがUnixの世界のロケールはもうほとんどUTF-8で統一されたので、Unixを使ってるプログラマーはファイルを開く時に文字コードを指定しなくてもUTF-8のファイルを開けると期待してしまうミスが多発してしまいます。

`set PYTHONUTF8=1` すると Python の UTF-8 mode というものが有効になり、ロケールやコードページに関係なくUTF-8を使うようになります。これで UTF-8 を期待したプログラムをWindows上でも動かせるようになります。

Answer (score 0):

自分も同じエラーでつまづいていました。

ユニコード関連のエラーのようで、
コントロールパネル → 時計と地域 → 地域 → 管理 → システムロケールの変更 → utf-8を使用
の後 `pip install markovify` でうまくいきました。